# Cumulative sums in R

Tags: r, sum, sequence, cumulative-sum

I want to compute the following term in R, but without using loops ("for" cycles):

[image]

So far, I already calculated it manually and tried to use sequence functions for both index variables i and j and integrated them in a cumsum function and summed up the returning vector.

```
i <- seq(1:10)
j <- seq(1:5)

sum(cumsum((i^5)/(10+j^i)))
```

However, the results do not match with my manual calculation, so this seems to be a wrong approach. Could anybody help me out on this?

Comment: hm. the length of i and j are different (10 and 5). for example, what would j equal when i = 6? would it go back to 1?

Comment: also, are you looking for one return value? or multiple for each combination of i,j?

Comment: `j <- 1:5;
sum(sapply(1:10, function(i) i^5 / (10+j^i)))`

Comment: @NovaEthos: You start with i = 1 and calculate it for all j (1:5) and yes, I need one return value, i.e. the result of the term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `outer`

```
> sum(outer(1:10, 1:5, FUN = function(i,j) i^5/(10+j^i)))
[1] 20845.76
```

Comment: it seems you do not need Vectorize

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
i <- seq(1:10)
j <- seq(1:5)
```

Solution 1:

```r
ir <- rep(i, each = length(j))
jr <- rep(j, length(i))
sum(ir^5 / (10 + jr^ir))
#> [1] 20845.76
```

Solution 2:

```r
d <- expand.grid(i=i,j=j)
with(d, sum(i^5 / (10 + j^i)))
#> [1] 20845.76
```

Solution 3: (@jogo)

```r
sum(sapply(i, function(i) i^5 / (10+j^i)))
#> [1] 20845.76
```

Comment: These solutions all work perfectly fine and give back the correct result, thank you @Edo!

Comment: You're welcome. However, I think @ThomasIsCoding's solution is the best one.